# Make the figure captions all empty in memoir

Tags: floats, captions, memoir

I'd like to suppress the text in all captions (ie. make all the captions empty, but leave the figure numbers) in in a document that uses the memoir class. I can do this if I use the caption package by including the line:
`\captionsetup{textformat=empty}`
But in this document I can't use the caption package.

Is there a way to do this with memoir commands? I could not find it in the memoir documentation, but that it not not to say it is not there. The captions in my document come in various shapes and sizes, some of them just using `\caption{}`, some of them using `\begin{sidecaption}`, should that be relevant.  Thanks.

Comment: The caption package works just fine with the memoir class, so what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that my document (a book) is now written. I just need a version with empty figure captions.  If I now add the caption package I obtain error messages such as

 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\sbox ...hbox {\color@setgroup #2\color@endgroup }
l.227 \end{sidecaption}

Perhaps my implementation is at fault?   However, I do have a workaround by redefining the makecaption command using:

    \renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \hbox to \hsize{\hfil #1\hfil}%
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip}`

and this seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: Which error do you get

Comment: My error is posted in my previous comment. Unfortunately it is poorly formatted and it seems I can no longer edit it.

Comment: Provide full code that generates an error like that. With no code we can't do much. Have you tried `\let\normalcaption\caption\renewcommand\caption[1]{\normalcaption{}}`

Comment: Your solution (`\let\normalcaption...`) works for regular figures. But it doesn't work for figure captions formatted with `\begin{sidecaption}`. The figure caption stays in full then. However, the earlier solution

     `\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{%
       \vskip\abovecaptionskip
       \hbox to \hsize{\hfil #1\hfil}%
       \vskip\belowcaptionskip}`

seems to work in that case too.  I'm afraid I can't immediately provide a mwe showing the origin of the error in using the caption package with memoir --- it's a long and complicated document, with lots of custom macros.

Comment: Then I will not be able to look at it until Monday (not at a pc)

Comment: Have you tried `\...caption{}`? Just don't put any text into the argument of the `\...caption` macros.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are suggesting, presumably a variant of @daleif 's suggestion. I tried, but no success there either.

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal example, I just tested `caption` package and `\captionsetup{textformat=empty}`, that removes the caption text on both normal figures and figures with `sidecaption`. If it doe snot for you we need to see some code.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. But the problem is not that `\captionsetup{textformat=empty}` does not work; rather, the problem was that using the caption package in memoir gave me errors, as per my first comment, so I preferred not to use `caption`. The document uses many other packages and macros, so it is possible that the problem there is not between `caption` and `memoir`, so getting an MWE may be a bit tricky.